# Bash script that runs in repl.it gives syntax error when in git alias

Tags: bash, git, git-config, git-alias

I'm trying to write a bash script for a git alias, to automate something.

I've written the script in repl.it, and it works without issue. However when I've taken the script and put it into my .gitconfig, and reduced it to a single line I'm now getting syntax errors.

```
 -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

This obviously isn't helpful at all since everything is on a single line.

Here is the script on one line as it exists in my git config

```
markaswip = "!f(){ fullBranchName='jm/branch/name'; IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< $fullBranchName; hasBranch=0; for element in "${array[@]}" do if [ "$element" = $"wip" ]; then hasBranch=1; fi; done; if [ $hasBranch = 1 ]; then echo "Has WIP tag already"; else appendedString=$(printf '%s/' "${newArray[@]}"); output=${appendedString%?}; echo $output; git branch -m ${commitmessage}; fi; }; f"
```

And here it is unrolled

```
f() {
    fullBranchName='test/branch/name';
    IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< $fullBranchName
    hasBranch=0;
    for element in "${array[@]}"
    do
        if [ "$element" = $"wip" ];
        then
        hasBranch=1;
        fi;
    done;
    
    if [ $hasBranch = 1 ]; 
    then
        echo "Has WIP tag already";
    else 
        newArray=( "${array[@]:0:1}" "wip" "${array[@]:1}" );
        appendedString=$(printf '%s/' "${newArray[@]}")
        #printf '%s/' "${newArray[@]}"
        output=${appendedString%?}
        echo $output;
        #git branch -m ${commitmessage};
    fi;
}
f;
```

Comment: You are missing ; after if [ "$element" = $"wip" ]

Comment: @RamanSailopal I already have `if [ "$element" = $"wip" ];` in the single line version

Comment: You will also need one after for element in "${array[@]}"

Comment: @Jake12342134 I guess it's better to extract the alias value to a standalone script and put it formatted to a `git-markaswip` executable shell script file without the `f`-wrapper in your PATH (or to the directory provided with `git --exec-path`) so that it would behave like an alias, and remain both human-readable and less error-prone.

Comment: The problem must be among double quotes, as you already have one at the beginning `markaswip = "`